# How to prevent username and password matches when changing a username?

Tags: authentication, passwords, hash, appsec, password-policy

Let's say that I have a system where one of the security requirements is preventing users from choosing a password that matches their username.  Usernames are not case sensitive but the passwords are.  The passwords are stored by the server using a secure hashing function that cannot be reversed.

When the account is created both the username and password are initially available in plaintext to the server for comparison.  We can compare them in memory (while disregarding case) to see if they match and instruct the user to choose a different password if they do.  Once this check is satisfied the password is securely hashed for storage while the username is stored in plaintext.  No problems meeting the requirement here.

When the user wants to change their password, or it is being changed for them, the server can retrieve their username record and compare it to the newly chosen password value (again ignoring case) to see if it matches.  No problems meeting the requirement here either.

However, the system also allows username changes.  During this ID change process the user hasn't necessarily provided their password in plaintext to the server.  They may have done so when they authenticated, but the server isn't going to keep that password stored in plaintext just in case they decide to change their username.  So the plaintext password is not available to check for a match against the newly chosen username value.

In an attempt to meet our requirement the server can use the same secure hashing function to hash the new username and compare it to the recorded hashed password.  If they match then the server can instruct the user to choose a different username.  However, since the username is not case sensitive this check might fail when it is arguably true.  If I submit "PwdRsch1" as a new username choice and my password is "pwdrsch1" then the system will allow it since the hashes won't match.  I -- or worse, an attacker -- could then later successfully authenticate with a matching username and password of "pwdrsch1".

We could force the username to lowercase before hashing and checking it against the password, but then the reverse scenario is possible.  The username would be checked as "pwdrsch1" against a password of "PwdRsch1" and allowed since these don't match.  But later I can successfully authenticate with a matching username and password of "PwdRsch1".

What reasonable options do I have to reduce this risk of a password matching a username that is not case sensitive?

Comment: Depending on the hash, brute force might be feasible: given a username with `N` letters (excluding numbers), the search space is only `2^N`.

Comment: Allowing users to change their username clearly creates problems for your password management, and with most of the systems I work would cause other complications. Is it really all that important? IME the best security comes from simplicity.

Comment: Separate display and login names are OK.

Comment: When the username is changed, force a reset of the password.

Comment: @DeerHunter I also thought about that, but didn't but it in an answer, because it might also not be desired (the name is changed for a reason after all). For example, a divorced person may not want to type in the last name of their ex each time they log in. So if you do something like that, meaningless login ids would be better (but probably also not desired, as they are harder to remember).

Comment: Why don't you just display some text in red that says "If your password is based on your username, there's a good chance somebody may guess it and steal your information."? I suspect this will take care of nearly every case. Programmatically enforced password complexity without attempts to educate users is this weird, ongoing nonproductive tradition. It's one of many reasons why nobody understands basic techniques for keeping their data safe, and why all these requirements and checks exist in the first place.

Comment: @DeerHunter: that's true but if anything makes it harder. If the account has a separate display and login name, and you're implementing this kind of measure at all, then you'd want to ensure that the password doesn't match either of them. So even if the login name cannot change, the fact that the display name can change means we still have this problem to solve (or fail/refuse to solve, as the case may be).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36752/discussion-on-question-by-pwdrsch-how-to-prevent-username-and-password-matches-w).

Comment: @user19474 by doing that you may your password hashing system much weaker as an attacker who gets hold of the hashes can attack the lowercased version first (much smaller search space) and then take their successes from that and apply it to the full versions of the hashes.

Comment: @PeterGreen, I don't understand your critique. If someone changes their ID from jsmith to jjones, and they are forced to select a new password, how is lowercase/upper case relevant?

Comment: If you consider that a login token is a combination of a username + password. Then any change in either username or password is a change in the login token. And requires verification IE through a completed login token -> the username + password. I have a hard time imagining a world where usernames and passwords are disjointed entities, they are simply a public and private token that together form your credential.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The only sensible way to get what you want is to ask for the password when a user changes their username.  This way the server always has the information needed to conduct an accurate comparison between the username and password during a change, and prevent matches.

As sensitive operations - such as changing passwords, or in your case usernames - should require a password anyways (to limit the damage of XSS), this shouldn't be a problem.

Your only other alternative is to try every possible case combination, hash it, and compare that to the stored hash when a user changes their username.

Comment: I agree that prompting for the password seems to be the most sensible solution when faced with user managed username changes.  However, some systems (e.g. Microsoft Active Directory) allow administrators to change usernames without user involvement.  In these situations the requirement for a user to provide their password isn't really compatible.  I suspect your other suggestion of hashing all variations may be the only workable option of meeting the requirement.  Otherwise we may have to be willing to allow for the risk of an admin-changed username matching a password.

Comment: @PwdRsch why would an administrator want to change usernames without user involvement? I can not imagine a legit use case.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good idea @emory. We would need to have someone who really understands the cryptography behind password hashes look at that idea and determine that storing multiple hashes of similar passwords doesn't help an attacker should they manage to steal both hashes. My general take is that password storage is complex and sticking with the tried-and-true is usually best.

Comment: I don't mean to imply the user would not be aware of the username change, just that they wouldn't be performing the change themselves.  This happens in situations where someone gets married and changes their last name, then their username is changed to match by company personnel.

Comment: @PwdRsch - Perhaps you can do the uname/password check on every login? Or on the first login after a username change? That said, how about you just fail to meet the requirements in those edge cases? They hardly seem worth worrying about.

Comment: @NeilSmithline I suspect ignoring these cases is what most system developers have chosen to do, but I was interested in hearing other ideas.

Comment: @emory brings up a good point. If the admin changes the username, what do you do if your policy is violated? Just not change the name? Use a different - incorrect - name? That doesn't make sense. (when the user changes it themselves, you could require a password change, but letting the admin change the password doesn't seem desirable; if it were, you could just make a password change mandatory and not have a problem)

Comment: @emory Yes, you could add character requirements/restrictions to ensure that a username can't ever be a valid password value, or vice versa. Feel free to expand on that as another answer to this question.

Comment: @tim I think you'd probably want to force a password change by the admin in that situation. Or force account lockout if that results in the user being unable to login with their now matching username/password until they complete a validation process and change their password.  Definitely not ideal from the user's perspective, but forced password changes rarely are.

Comment: @NeilSmithline I'd consider writing up your options of checking for matches during ever login or only logins following a username change as an answer since it seems reasonable and I don't want it to just be buried in the comments.

Comment: If the admin changes the username, you could set a flag that the password needs to be changed. A link is sent to the user, notifying the change. The very next time that user logins, the password has to be changed. In my case, I always try to force the use of paraphrases which are way longer than usernames. Even better, ditch the password and use keys instead.

Comment: @lepe in such a case if the database was leaked, one could simply look for the existence of such a flag and there is a high probably of the password being in plaintext in the username field

Comment: @emory an administrator might want to change a username for someone if their name changes.  The easiest example is where the username is made up of, say, surname and first initial.  This could change when a person gets married and therefore need changing on a system.  A normal user then might not be able to change their password.  Similarly, administrators might have a pile of requests to deal with, so it might not be practical to have them there to enter their password at the time of the username change.

Comment: Strongly agreed with @tim and emory : there's no legit and - actually - sane case for "not-a-user-himself" changes account's username and password. If a *legitimate* password change occures - you can prompt for old and new pass. If a username is desired to be changed too - OK, ask for a new one, same pass request form, just one extra line.

Comment: @gabe3886: More to the point, there's no reason the admin should need to know the user's password.  Simply make the system check at each login attempt whether the username and password match, and if they do set the password to expire very soon (giving the user a heads-up that it will be necessary to pick a new password is probably better than putting them on the spot).

Comment: @Dezza yes, but usually such a flag prohibits users from logging, no matter what the password

Comment: @Dezza I see your point. Why do you think is of "high" chance? I think there is a "low" chance that the new username will match the previous password. How about this: When the username is changed, the password is set to a random (temp) password which will be changed by the user on link click. In addition to the many alternatives to verify the user's link, you could include the - old password hash - hash as a parameter in the link. That way, you can ask for the old password to set the new one without leaving the old hash in the database. As kw4nta said, the user can't login when the flag is on.

Answer (score 13):

Going against the grain a little - *don't* care whether the username is changed to a "substantially similar" string as the password.  Warn users about the danger of selecting the same password and check for the *identical* match.

No matter how many rules you put in place, if the user is determined they'll find a way around them.  If you must, prompt for the password upon username change so you can force them to the same casing, or just let it through and check the next time they log in and force a user/pass change then.

The *only* time any of this matters is if your users are subjected to a targeted attack.  If a random script kiddie (or some other opportunist) gets ahold of the user list, they have way more sophisticated tools to break those passwords than trying to match the username.  So does the targeted attacker, for that matter, but they may start with simple things they can type into the keyboard themselves.  And if it's an intelligent person trying to break the password "PwdRsch1", are you really going to be safe just checking case differences?  What about "pwdr5ch1"? "PwdRsch2"? "1hcsRdwP"? You can write rules for any of these scenarios you can think of, but either there'll be one you forgot or you'll make it so difficult to select a username/password combo that they'll just wind up using "P4ssw0rd!" and be done with it.

Education is the *only* way to get your users to use genuinely secure passwords, and there will always be those that don't comply.

Comment: I do agree that a determined user can choose a weaker password than we might like, despite the policy rules or other controls we use to prevent bad choices.  However, I don't feel like this requirement (as stated) is taking things too far.  Pair that technical control with education as you suggest and hopefully we gain the security advantages of both.  However, just because most attackers will make guesses beyond a password matching the username doesn't mean that we shouldn't attempt to enforce this rule. We still need to eliminate the low hanging fruit.

Comment: @PwdRsch I don't disagree, my point, I suppose, is that you don't need to *hide* what you're doing from the user - explicitly requiring them to enter their password when making a name change, or running the same check the next time they log in after an admin changed their name, actually improves the education because it gives them a reason to pay attention.  That said, if an admin is able to, essentially, *accidentally* guess a user's password when selecting their username, then that's a reason to offload the education onto the user *anyway* because that was a horribly chosen password.

Answer (score 8):

Let's say the username has 10 letters in it. That's 1024 different combinations of upper and lower case. Check them all.

Don't store the lower case password hash. That 1024 may seem inconvenient to you, but it's the difference between a day and three years for a attacker.

Comment: Depending on the hashing and the hardware, it may take around a minute for that. If an admin changes the username that might be fine (if it is clearly displayed that this is a slow process), if a user changes it, a minute might not be acceptable. It may result in problems, eg users resubmitting forms and then not knowing with what username they ended up with, or users closing the window before they get the message that their new username is not acceptable.

Comment: @tim It needs to be slow. Otherwise, an attacker who takes over the server or has a replica of the server could simply keep trying to change the username until they figure out the password (in practice they could make something much better than the server). You can trade speed for space though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt

Comment: If *you* (assumed to be a non-expert password cracker) can brute force it, an attacker can do the same much, much quicker.  If you *are* an expert password cracker, then you already know the futility of what you're doing.

Comment: @Jason you don't need to know the password, just make sure that the username isn't the password.

Answer (score 4):

You should force userids and passwords to come from different sets.  In the comments it appears that the userid must follow from the user's legal name in a formulaic way "John Smith" -> "jsmith" and "Jane Doe" -> "jdoe".  Then if Jane marries John and takes his name, then her user id must change to something like "jsmith2"

So you could stipulate that the first character in a password must be a symbol or that the password must contain a symbol.

If userids are truncated at 8 characters you could require that passwords must contain at least 9 characters.

You could take the cartesian product of a list surnames and a list of given names and use that as a blacklist for passwords.  If a employee has a name that was not on your list, add it, and as people change passwords the problem will fix itself.

Comment: Brenda Utthead would have a colorable objection to your proposed policy, especially if usernames are used in public communication.

Comment: @DamianYerrick To be clear it is my understanding that the OP has a strict requirement that userids be derived formulaicly from legal names and not match passwords.  I think users should be able to pick their own userid which need not resemble their legal name.  Brenda's objection has more to do with OP's requirements than my policy.

Comment: @DamianYerrick in comments, the OP said that if Brenda Smith (userid bsmith, password butthead) married Rick Utthead (userid rutthead) and took Utthead's name, then the admin would have to change Brenda's userid to butthead but that would be a problem because now her userid and password are the same.

Comment: @DamianYerrick but if you believe that the userid matching the password is not the big problem in Brenda's scenario, then I have to agree.

Comment: @DamianYerrick Cisco Systems actually did that, and seemed spectacularly unlucky with their staff names, along the lines of Chris Rapherty, Simon Hitchin, and so forth. I believe they also truncated their usernames to 8 letters. Much amusement (outside Cisco) ensued.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, I'm only mentioning it so that people **don't do this**.

You might decide that it would make sense to store, in addition to the regular hash of their case-sensitive password, a hash of their password converted to all-lowercase.

This would certainly solve your problem - you just lowercase the username that you're changing to, and compare it to this stored hash of the lowercased password.

The obvious downside is that this partly defeats the purpose of a hashed password in the first place: to make attacks on your password list much harder. An attacker gaining access to your hashed password lists would be able to attack the far weaker (2^n times weaker) lower-case hash instead of the case sensitive hash.

So the other options mentioned (asking for the password at time of change; trying all case permutations if an admin changes it, ideally in most-likely order first) seem far better bets.

Comment: This was one of the early answers offered as a seemingly good option that the poster then later deleted once people chimed in with the warnings you list. ;)  I agree that the tradeoffs in security don't really make this worthwhile.

Comment: @PwdRsch Oh, thanks - I didn't realize. This answer, for once, I'd be perfectly fine to see getting uncommented downvotes :)

Comment: @DewiMorgan You could make it CW... that way you wouldn't lose rep for the downvotes.

Comment: Ooh, thanks, @wizzwizz4, I didn't know that. Done! Feels kinda... naughty and exploitatious, though :(

Answer (score 2):

Some great answers already, but here is an alternative way to approach this issue. Instead of trying to compare the new username to the existing password, you could simply force a password change anytime a user changes their username.

Naturally, you would want to warn users that changing the username will require changing the password, but you can then easily use whatever process already exists to check new passwords against usernames.

Answer (score 0):

While the most sensible solution has been already mentioned and accepted, namely asking for the password on user name change because you should be doing that anyway. An alternative is to also store the hash of the lowercase password (with a different salt?) and comparing the all lower case username to that.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to prevent users from picking dumb passwords is by forcing password **generation** policies (as opposed to the woefully common password *format* policies).

Now, if you don't have that much authority over your users (most websites don't), you should at least tell them to generate their passwords with a password manager (and generate their master password with [dice](https://www.eff.org/dice)), and you might be able to make it difficult to disobey this policy:

One way you might do this is by making your password field not accept keyboard input, but instead only pasted data or machine-typed data (I recommend checking the speed at which characters are entered). Then you can have the box explaining the password policy be outlined in red or something to draw their attention back to it.